# Regular Expression to replace non alpha characters with spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have been trying to build a regular expression but haven't been able to get one specific condition to work.

I want a regex to remove all non alpha characters with the exception of dash (`-`). Dashes should only be replaced if they are prefixed by a space.

I.e.

```
TEST-TEST -TEST#TEST.TEST
```

should be changed to

```
TEST-TEST TEST TEST TEST
```

I had been using `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` but haven't been able to include one OR condition init.

Comment: According to you example, it looks like you want to keep spaces as well?

Comment: or replace non-alpha chars with spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I came up with `(\s-|[^A-Za-z0-9-])`... It will remove all non alphanumerics but keep the "-" except if there is a space before it " -"

Test using sed in Linux, at the moment I don't have access to VS or Mono to test in C#

```
echo "TEST-TEST -TEST#TEST.TEST -1234" | sed 's/\(\s-\|[^A-Za-z0-9-]\)/ /g'
```

Output

```
TEST-TEST TEST TEST TEST 1234
```

- () and | are used for the OR condition
- We first remove all " -" using `\s-`
- next we keep all alphanumerics and "-" with `[^A-Za-z0-9-]`

Comment: `var regex = new Regex(@"(\s-|[^A-Za-z0-9-])"); string result = regex.Replace("TEST-TEST -TEST#TEST.TEST", " ");`

Answer (score 2):

```
// Skip over '-', grab non-word characters or the ' -' sequence to replace
string pattern = @"(?!-)(\W| -)+";  
string replacement = "";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string result = regex .Replace("Replace - this *@#&@#* string-already", replacement);
```

The (?!-) is a zero-width negative lookahead assertion that will skip over the '-' symbol... the second group will match it if it's preceded by a space.

If you're trying to substitute a space instead of completely removing the characters, just change to

```
string replacement = " ";
```

the pattern is greedy, so it will replace groups of non-word characters with a single space.