# Create a single string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

How do i read the following text into a single string using c# regex?

**EDIT **
    :70://this is a string 
    //this is continuation of 
    string even more text 13

this is stored in a c# List object

so for example, the above needs to return

```
this is a string this is continuation of string even more tex
```

I've thought something like this would do the job, but it doesn't return any group values

```
foreach (string in inputstring)
{
   string[] words
   words = str.Split(default(string[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   foreach (string word in words)
   {
      stringbuilder.Append(word + " ");
   }
 }
 Match strMatch = Regex.Match(stringBuilder, @"[^\W\d]+");
 if(strMatch.Success)
 {
     string key = strMatch.Groups[1].Value;
 }
```

perhaps, i'm going about this all wrong, but i need to use the regex expression to formualte a single string from the example string.

Comment: This code won't compile - you are missing a variable name for string in your `foreach`. Also, you're not using said variable anywhere

Comment: Search for a regex that *replaces* any non-alpha characters, ie. [a-zA-Z] including carriage returns and line feeds. By replacing everything you don't need with string.empty, you should achieve your goal.

Comment: Kind of like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220172/regular-expression-to-replace-non-alpha-characters-with-spaces

Comment: I've not listed all the code, so i'm not too concerned it won't compile! - it's just example code - hey but thanks for the minus :-)

Comment: For some reason the example string ended up on one line, this may of led to the confusion, and some of hte responses. Checking for a regex for a single string would be easy.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee +1 By the way,is it essential to do this in regular expressions ?

Comment: @CSharpNewBee I really have no idea what is going on with your question now. I have tried to answer below with what you originally put.

Comment: yes, sorry was on a call, so couldn't test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var input = @":70://this is a string //this is continuation of string even more text 13";

Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\w\s]|[\d]", "").Trim();
// returns: this is a string this is continuation of string even more text
```

Explanation of regex:

```
[^ ... ] = character set not matching what's inside
\w       = word character
\s       = whitespace character
|        = or
\d       = digit
```

Alternatively you could use the regex `[^A-Za-z\s]` which reads "don't match capital letters, lowercase letters or whitespace".